# Sub record error while using LDT

Tags: java, aerospike, nosql

I am using LDT map and at first got this error.

```
com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: Error Code 1424: LDT-Sub Record Create Error
```

I was able to remove it with the help of `ldt-enabled true` in `aerospike.conf`
but now I am running into

```
com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: Error Code 1422: LDT-Sub Record Open Error
```

Code snippet :

```
for (Entry<String, Map<String, Object>> myLdtBin: myLdtMap.entrySet()) {
    LargeMap lmap = client.getLargeMap(myWritePolicy, myKey, myLdtBin.getKey() , null);
    lmap.put(myLdtBin.getValue()); //<-- Error here
}
```

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 5):

Aerospike has put in major stability fixes in 3.4.1 for LDT. Please see if this issue appears still in 3.4.1

Also, the recommended data-structure to use is LLIST. It is backed by a B+ tree, and is the most extensible.

Comment: This isn't really so much of an answer as it should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the actual problem is, but I hit the same problem today. I'm using LSTACK, but internally it uses a LIST. My problem was that the default LSTACK configuration is quite limited in terms of list elements count. I was trying to insert about 200 elements in a LSTACK, but it seems the default config allows a maximum of 100. Take a look at the [LDT Configuration page](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/ldt_configuration.html). Here is a simple example of a extended configuration for a LSTACK:

```
local userModule = {};

function userModule.adjust_settings( ldtMap )
  local ldt_settings=require('ldt/settings_lstack');
  ldt_settings.use_package( ldtMap, "ListMediumObject" );

  ldt_settings.set_coldlist_max( ldtMap, 100 )
  ldt_settings.set_colddir_rec_max( ldtMap, 10000 )
end

return userModule;
```

Just add *your* config to a Lua UDF, and pass it as 'userModule' param to `put` method. Make some tests to determine the correct configuration you might need. Look at `/opt/aerospike/sys/udf/lua/ldt/settings_llist.lua` for the current LLIST settings and what can be changed.

EDIT:

Here is the default configuration for LLIST:

```
-- LLIST Inner Node Settings
ldtMap[LS.NodeListMax] = 100;  -- Max # of items (key+digest)
ldtMap[LS.NodeByteCountMax] = 0; -- Max # of BYTES

-- LLIST Tree Leaves (Data Pages)
ldtMap[LS.LeafListMax] = 100;  -- Max # of items
ldtMap[LS.LeafByteCountMax] = 0; -- Max # of BYTES per data page
```

It seems the max default LLIST size is 100. Change it and test.